# Table name if prefixed with user id ASP.NET Core 3.1 EF database migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a Aps.net Core 3.1 project which is directly connected to a database on my test server. The problem I am facing is when I am running any migration, the table names are getting prefixed with the "user id" from the connection string that is set in the appsettings.json file.

For Example, if the user id is "demo_user3" in the appstrings.json file then the the table is created with a name "demo_user3.EmployeeInformation" instead of "EmployeeInformation".

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not set default schema in code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(connectionStringName);
}
```

Comment: Do I add this line to the code? I do not have this line in my ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs file.

Comment: do you have schema name on your table/model definition like this `[Table("blogs", Schema = "blogging")]`?

Comment: I do not have that.

Comment: Are you using IDbContextSchema  somewhere?

Comment: Thanks to you, I figured it out. Had to add the above code in my ApplicationDBContext file. 
Thank you.

Comment: what is connectionStringName?  where does it come from?

Comment: @dezox connectionStringName is a variable in your context file